# Postgresql: How can we insert only time and date into a variable using timestamp?

Tags: postgresql

Error: Getting an error near time format while inserting.

Example:

```
--Table "Test"  

create table test  
(  
name varchar(10),  
date1 timestamp,  
time1 timestamp  
);  

-- Insertion  
insert into test values('xyz','03/03/2014','02:03:04');
```

Comment: Do not rely on implicit data type conversion. Either use `to_date()` to convert a string to a date, or use ANSI date literals.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The type 'timestamp' holds both a time and a date. You are trying to insert the date and time separately. Either use date and time types:

```
--Table "Test"

create table test
(
name varchar(10),
date1 date,
time1 time
);

-- Insertion
insert into test values('xyz','03/03/2014','02:03:04');
```

Or, just use one field:

```
--Table "Test"

create table test
(
name varchar(10),
datetime timestamp

);

-- Insertion
insert into test values('xyz','03/03/2014 02:03:04');
```

I recommend this second approach, as the set of operators and functions available is much larger and it is easier to compare timestamps.

Comment: Isn't the postgresql's format for date is dd-mm-yyyy (if you have set datestyle dmy).

Comment: @soobster `dd-mm-yyyy` or `dd/mm/yyyy` [will be accepted as input](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT) in dmy mode (as well as other formats).  I would normally use `yyyy-mm-dd` in my own code, but here I am just reflecting OPs inputs